# expected a character that can start a name, such as a letter, `$`, or `_` in Gatsby theme

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I have used Smooth docs Gatsby theme and while trying to run project "Gatsby Develop" terminal shows this errors ..

[image: error]

I'm reading mdx files in my project and that mdx files has js and other languages codes too for documentation perpose.

here is dependencies which i have installed in package.json

[image: dependencies]

and if required i can share code of gatsby-config.js and gatsby-node.js

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same error when having an unescaped `<!` in my mdx files.
Most likely some html comment (`<!-- some comment -->`).

The error message hints you how to create comments

> (note: to create a comment in MDX, use `{/* text */}`)

It's also described [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx/#updating-mdx-content).

To help you spot such things, you could look for mdx extensions/plugins for your IDE, e.g. this [mdx extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=unifiedjs.vscode-mdx) for VSCode or follow the advice from the link above and install [eslint-mdx](https://github.com/mdx-js/eslint-mdx) to validate your mdx files.

With eslint-mdx you will also see exactly the file and code line where your mdx files are broken. Somehow this is not logged in the error message when you try to run the project.